# Why terraform validate is giving error on my declared varaibles?

Tags: terraform, devops

```
├── comp-B
│   ├── comp-B.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   ├── variables.tf
│   └── vcn.tf
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── provider.tf
└── variables.tf
```

**The argument "vcns" is required, but no definition was found**
I have defined the vcns in comp-B/variables.tf and vcns value in terraform.tfvars
But still getting the error.

Comment: Where are you running the code from, root module or `comp-B`? Can you add the parts of code which are referencing that value? Otherwise it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your source code I can't be sure, but I'm assuming that what you mean by this directory tree is that the root `main.tf` contains a `module` block with `source = "./comp-B"`, and the error you saw is indicating that module block as the source of the problem.

The `terraform.tfvars` file is only for setting variables in the root module, which means the ones defined in your root `variables.tf`. If you want to pass those values on to a child module then you can include an argument in the `module` block which refers to the variable:

```
module "example" {
  source = "./comp-B"

  vcns = var.vcns
  # ...
}
```